# Circle Shadow Experiment

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, graphics

I'm trying to create a light system, with the midpoint algorithm and Bresenham Line Algorithm. I'm trying to redraw all the time (1 option) or redraw when I need to.  When the circles are too big it becomes a bit laggy.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/876mv13n/)

```
function Light(x, y, range)
{
    this.CordX = x;
    this.CordY = y;
    this.LuminosityRange = range;
}
   setInterval(function(){
        stats.begin(); // Begin to count FPS
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Width, Height); // Clear Canvas

        // STEP 1 -- DRAW THE BACKGROUND (BLACK)
        for(var y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {    
            for(var x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                var index = x + (y * Width),
                    indexColor = index * 4;

                shadowBitMapData[indexColor + 0] = shadowBitMapData[indexColor + 1] = shadowBitMapData[indexColor + 2] = 0;
                shadowBitMapData[indexColor + 3] = 255;
            }
        }

        // SETEP 2 -- DRAW THE LIGHT
        for(var light = 0; light < lamps.length; light++)
        {
            var currentLight = lamps[light];
            var xCL = ~~currentLight.CordX,
                yCL = ~~currentLight.CordY,
                iCL = xCL + (yCL * Width),
                rCL = ~~currentLight.LuminosityRange;

            // MidPoint Algorithm
            var xMP = rCL,
                yMP = 0,
                rEMP = 1 - xMP;

            while(xMP >= yMP)
            {

                var x1 = xMP + xCL,
                    x2 = yMP + xCL,
                    x3 = -xMP + xCL,
                    x4 = -yMP + xCL;

                var y1 = yMP + yCL,
                    y2 = xMP + yCL,
                    y3 = -yMP + yCL,
                    y4 = -xMP + yCL;

                var index1 = x1 + (y1 * Width);
                var index2 = x2 + (y2 * Width);

                var index3 = x3 + (y1 * Width);
                var index4 = x4 + (y2 * Width);

                var index5 = x3 + (y3 * Width);
                var index6 = x4 + (y4 * Width);

                var index7 = x1 + (y3 * Width);
                var index8 = x2 + (y4 * Width);


                // Fill Top
                //shadowBitMapData[index6 * 4 + 3] = 0;
                //shadowBitMapData[index8 * 4 + 3] = 0;
                BresenhamLine(x4, y4, x2, y4, shadowBitMapData, Width);

                // Fill Mid Top
                //shadowBitMapData[index5 * 4 + 3] = 0;
                //shadowBitMapData[index7 * 4 + 3] = 0;
                BresenhamLine(x3, y3, x1, y3, shadowBitMapData, Width);

                // Fill Mid Bottom
                //shadowBitMapData[index1 * 4 + 3] = 0;
                //shadowBitMapData[index3 * 4 + 3] = 0;
                BresenhamLine(x1, y1, x3, y1, shadowBitMapData, Width);

                // Fill Bottom
                //shadowBitMapData[index2 * 4 + 3] = 0;
                //shadowBitMapData[index4 * 4 + 3] = 0;
                BresenhamLine(x2, y2, x4, y2, shadowBitMapData, Width);

                yMP++;

                if (rEMP < 0)
                {
                    rEMP += 2 * yMP + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    xMP--;
                    rEMP += 2 * (yMP - xMP + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(shadowBitMap, 0, 0); // Draw Shadow
        stats.end(); // End to count FPS
    }, 1000 / 60);

function BresenhamLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, bitmap, Width)
{
    var dx = Math.abs(x0 - x1);
    var dy = Math.abs(y0 - y1);

    var sx = x1 < x0 ? 1 : -1; 
    var sy = y1 < y0 ? 1 : -1; 

    var err = dx - dy;
    var e2;

    var lm = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        bitmap[(x1 + y1 * Width) * 4 + 3] = 0;

        if (x1 == x0 && y1 == y0) break;

        e2 = 2 * err;
        if (e2 > -dy) 
        {
            err = err - dy;
            x1 = x1 + sx;
        }

        if (e2 < dx) 
        {
            err = err + dx;
            y1 = y1 + sy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Greetings, it would help us tremendously if you could set up a working jsbin/jsfiddle/plnkr and provide us the link.

Comment: Also, can you define what *too big* is ?

Comment: Sorry!, here is the example! http://jsfiddle.net/876mv13n/

Comment: Minor point: `~~` is cute but doesn't offer a huge performance gain over `Math.floor()`, which is infinitely more readable.

Comment: Why are you not using the drawing functions of the canvas?

Answer (score 2):

### Don't Reinvent the Wheel

In your "STEP 1", you are manually setting each pixel of the background to black. This is expensive and unnecessary. You can simply draw a black rectangle the size of the canvas:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, Width, Height);
```

Next, in "STEP 2" why are you using your own line drawing routines? You could simply call the built-in routines, like:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
ctx.stroke();
```

And to draw circles, you can use the `arc()` method:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2.0 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb (1, 1, 1);"
ctx.fill();
```

This will likely be much faster than rolling your own.

### Naming

I find your variable names hard to read and understand. Names like `xCL`, `yCL` and `xMP`, `yMP` are not very descriptive. Maybe `centerX`, `centerY` and `midPointX` and `midPointY` instead?

Also, `iCL` seems to be unused. It can be removed.

### Abuse of Lambdas

Your entire drawing function (the main purpose of your program) is an anonymous function passed as an argument to another function. It's difficult to follow the flow of it all, and it's odd that the most important thing in your code is a single argument to a function that merely collects stats.

And then you mix in stats collection in the actual function that does the drawing. I'd separate it all out, like this:

```
function draw()
{
... all the drawing code...
}

function collectDrawStats()
{
    stats.begin();
    draw();
    stats.end();
}

setInterval(collectDrawStats(), 1000 / 60);
```

### Avoid Magic Numbers

What is the `1000 / 60` in the call to `setInterval()`? Does that have something to do with the refresh rate being 60 fps? You should create a named constant that tells a reader what it means. Is it milliseconds per 60th of a second? If so, what's the significance of that?